# I am interested in conducting a trend analysis with random subject/item intercepts/slopes, in R

Tags: r, logistic, trend

I have a dichotomous outcome variable and am using an IV with three levels.

Is it possible to run a trend analysis in which the DV is the likelihood of success, while also including random subject and item intercepts/slopes?

I am looking to run this in R.

Thanks!

Comment: Are there any covariates? What sorts of  counts per "subject" and "item" are we dealing with? (I'm worried you may be creating a saturated model with the number of parameters you are proposing and you will need sufficient data to support that proposal.) And without any data this is starting to sound like a stats consult question rather than an R coding question.

Comment: Well I would like to know how to code this analysis in R?

One covariate.

30 ish subjects, 72 items (24 of each of the three levels).

Comment: Well, Dave ... HAL9000 might say "Sorry, Dave. I can't do that." You should edit your question with sufficient code to allow a proper test case to be analyzed. You have more covariates than subjects, so you should be very clear about what you expect. "Trends" along what axes? (Still sounds like a stats consult to me.)